# Delay jQuery scripts

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, facebook, jscrollpane

I am using [jScrollPane](http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/) for a simple website because I decided to go with a centered, fixed div with height of 600px. Everything works fine except when I added facebook comment, the scrollable dive does not wait for facebook comment block to load, so the comment box is not viewable!

I am calling the function to the scroll script inside the `HEAD` tag:

```
        <script type="text/javascript" id="sourcecode">
        $(function()
        {
            $('.scroll-pane').jScrollPane();
        });
       </script>
```

And here is the scripto the facebook comment box that is inserted immideatly after `BODY` tag:

```
        <div id="fb-root"></div>
    <script>(function(d, s, id) {
            var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
            if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
            js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
            js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_GB/all.js#xfbml=1";
            fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
        }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
```

And here is the  `CSS` that defines style for my scrollable DIV:

```
.scroll-pane
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 600px; 
    overflow: auto; 
}
```

As I said, the scrolled div works fine, But I think I should somehow make it to wait for that facebook comment box to load. Any suggestion is appriciated!

**UPDATE**

I found here that the scrolled div can check for dynamic content: [dynamic content](http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/dynamic_content.html), but I have no idea where to put the follwoing code in my html file:

```
$(function()
{
    var settings = {
        showArrows: true
    };
    var pane = $('.scroll-pane')
    pane.jScrollPane(settings);
    var api = pane.data('jsp');
    var i = 1;
)};
```

Comment: Why do you send `document` as a parameter? and you're looking for `<script>` tags elements? It's a very weird code.

Comment: well I am too noob to answer your question, I just followed the tutorial in the first link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Waiting for the fb comment box to be ready is not that easy, but you can a) wait for a fixed time and initialize the jScrollPane then, hoping that the fb box is ready by that time (like 1 or 2 seconds).

```
<script type="text/javascript" id="sourcecode">
$(function() {                        // <-- Wait for the DOM to be ready
    setTimeout(function() {
        // Now initialize the pane as before:
        $('.scroll-pane').jScrollPane();
    }, 1000);                         // <-- Waiting an additional 1000ms
});
</script>
```

Or b) if you want to got with the example for dynamic content (from that link you provided), you would just reinitialize the jScrollPane every 100ms or whatever:

```
<script type="text/javascript" id="sourcecode">
$(function() {
    // As you already did, initialize the scrollpane first:
    var pane = $('.scroll-pane');
    pane.jScrollPane();

    // Store an access handler (api) in a variable
    var api = pane.data('jsp');

    // Set timer to reinitialize the pane every 250ms
    setInterval(api.reinitialise, 250);
});
</script>
```

Comment: Would my method not work as well? Or is the onSuccess simply going to check if the div exists and not if the function has actually been run? I assumed it would work based on that the fb-root div would be being modified by the function and if not complete then my function would not run until it was completed with 'onSuccess' or at worst could use event.target to find if the function inside the fb-root div was already ran upon...

Comment: @ityler22 I'm not really sure about that, IMHO means "onSuccess" only that the facebook javascript is loaded - but loading the actual facebook content (like a comment box) consumes additional time. But you may be right. And if it works, your solution would definitely be much more elegant.

Answer (score 2):

I would place everything you doing jquery/javascript wise inside [.ready()](http://api.jquery.com/ready/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  // Handler for .ready() called.
});
```

This will ensure that the entire page is loaded until anything jquery runs.

This is slightly more in-depth using your div id.

```
$(document).ready(function() 
 $("#fb-root").function({
    'onSuccess': function() {

      // Perform all of these now that fbook box is loaded
    }
  )};
)};
```